# Sublime Terminal - No such file or directory

Tags: sublime-text

I'm trying to run a simple C code, "hello world" type of, and everytime I build it, in the terminal it prints out the path of the code file, and the following message next to it:

`No such file or directory`.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Would you be able to post the path in the error message in case there's a formatting error?

Comment: @Kyle to post the whole error message?